# JavaFX not working on my macbook (m1 chipset)

Tags: java, macos, maven, javafx, apple-m1

I am trying to start a javaFX project in intelij on my macbook with a m1 chip.
When I am trying to run my main file my program crashes and says "java quit unexpectedly"

This is the log when java quits:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000115378ac8, pid=20632, tid=259
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu16.32+15-CA (16.0.2+7) (build 16.0.2+7)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu16.32+15-CA (16.0.2+7, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-aarch64)
# Problematic frame:
# J 343 c2 java.lang.StringLatin1.indexOf([BII)I java.base@16.0.2 (36 bytes) @ 0x0000000115378ac8 [0x0000000115378ac0+0x0000000000000008]
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://www.azul.com/support/
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: --module-path=/Users/moemenhussein/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/18.0.1/javafx-base-18.0.1-mac-aarch64.jar:/Users/moemenhussein/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/18.0.1/javafx-base-18.0.1.jar:/Users/moemenhussein/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/18.0.1/javafx-controls-18.0.1-mac-aarch64.jar:/Users/moemenhussein/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/18.0.1/javafx-controls-18.0.1.jar:/Users/moemenhussein/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/18.0.1/javafx-fxml-18.0.1-mac-aarch64.jar:/Users/moemenhussein/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/18.0.1/javafx-fxml-18.0.1.jar:/Users/moemenhussein/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/18.0.1/javafx-graphics-18.0.1-mac-aarch64.jar:/Users/moemenhussein/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/18.0.1/javafx-graphics-18.0.1.jar --add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics Main

Host: MacBookAir10,1 arm64 1 MHz, 8 cores, 8G, Darwin 21.4.0, macOS 12.3.1 (21E258)
Time: Mon May 16 20:00:48 2022 CEST elapsed time: 0.886937 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000015700e800):  JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_Java, id=259, stack(0x000000016ae14000,0x000000016ce14000)]

Stack: [0x000000016ae14000,0x000000016ce14000],  sp=0x000000016c62bd10,  free space=24671k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
J 343 c2 java.lang.StringLatin1.indexOf([BII)I java.base@16.0.2 (36 bytes) @ 0x0000000115378ac8 [0x0000000115378ac0+0x0000000000000008]
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4217e4]  _ZN13InstanceKlass17allocate_objArrayEiiP6Thread+0x144
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x80609c]  _ZN11OptoRuntime11new_array_CEP5KlassiP10JavaThread+0x1ec


siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr: 0x000000016c617d10

Register to memory mapping:

 x0=0x00000007403e7d88 is an oop: java.lang.String 
{0x00000007403e7d88} - klass: 'java/lang/String'
 x1=0x000000074034a248 is an oop: [B 
{0x000000074034a248} - klass: {type array byte}
 - length: 1
 x2=0x000000000000003f is an unknown value
 x3=0x0 is NULL
 x4=0x0 is NULL
 x5=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
 x6=0x0000000740353a78 is an oop: java.lang.String 
{0x0000000740353a78} - klass: 'java/lang/String'
 x7=0x0 is NULL
 x8=0x00000000000409f8 is an unknown value
 x9=
```

When I try to run the project from the maven tab. The "javafx:run". I am getting this error:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.6:run (default-cli) @ El_Dorado ---
[INFO] Toolchain in javafx-maven-plugin null
Loading library prism_es2 from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/moemenhussein/.openjfx/cache/18.0.1+2/libprism_es2.dylib: dlopen(/Users/moemenhussein/.openjfx/cache/18.0.1+2/libprism_es2.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/moemenhussein/.openjfx/cache/18.0.1+2/libprism_es2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/moemenhussein/.openjfx/cache/18.0.1+2/libprism_es2.dylib: dlopen(/Users/moemenhussein/.openjfx/cache/18.0.1+2/libprism_es2.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/moemenhussein/.openjfx/cache/18.0.1+2/libprism_es2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2383)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:746)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:217)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:197)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:138)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:54)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.lambda$static$0(ES2Pipeline.java:63)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:52)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:92)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Loading library prism_sw from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/moemenhussein/.openjfx/cache/18.0.1+2/libprism_sw.dylib: dlopen(/Users/moemenhussein/.openjfx/cache/18.0.1+2/libprism_sw.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/moemenhussein/.openjfx/cache/18.0.1+2/libprism_sw.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/moemenhussein/.openjfx/cache/18.0.1+2/libprism_sw.dylib: dlopen(/Users/moemenhussein/.openjfx/cache/18.0.1+2/libprism_sw.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/moemenhussein/.openjfx/cache/18.0.1+2/libprism_sw.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2383)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:746)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:217)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:197)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:138)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:54)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.lambda$static$0(SWPipeline.java:43)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.<clinit>(SWPipeline.java:42)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:92)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:266)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:278)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    ... 5 more
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

I do not really know what to do anymore, I've added this to my "vm options" (I have also added the lib folder to my Project Structure under Modules -> dependencies):

```
--module-path "/Users/moemenhussein/Documents/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-18.0.1/lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

And my pom.xml does look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>El_Dorado</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: JavaFX settings look good for M1 (18.0.1 should work perfectly fine), but your JDK (16.0.2) might not work. Try using at least JDK 17.0.2 and make sure you download the version for aarch64.

Comment: @JoséPereda, Thank you! It worked. I am now using Eclipse Temurin 18.0.1. I've downloaded it from https://adoptium.net

Comment: I suggest you write, post, and accept an Answer to your own Question, for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer in my comments from Jose Pereda saying that I have to use a newer JDK. I was using JDK 16.0.2 and he said that I had to use at least JDK 17.0.2.

So I upgraded my JDK to 18.0.1. You can download the JDK in intelij self, but that did not work for me. So I've downloaded it from https://adoptium.net/ and downloading the aarch64 version.