# JavaFX java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError only in JAR and only on M1 Mac

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I'm getting the following error when trying to play a `MediaPlayer` sound with the jar file created. There is absolutely no problem playing sounds if I run the program directly in VSCode and the jar also worked properly on my previous non M1 iMac Pro which was running High Sierra. I'm using Maven and my Mac uses Monterey.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/media/Media
    at com.parler.utils.Prononce.playSound(Prononce.java:94)
    at com.parler.TextBubble.lambda$1(TextBubble.java:76)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3566)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3870)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1854)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2587)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:413)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.media.Media
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 34 more
```

VSCode terminal:

```
% java -version
java version "17.0.3.1" 2022-04-22 LTS
```

Mac terminal:

```
java -version
java version "17.0.3.1" 2022-04-22 LTS
```

Comment: Javafx is no longer bundled with the JVM and you probably used an old one on your old machine.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen So the JVM is not required to launch a JAR?

Comment: That's not what they said. Back in Java 11, the JavaFX library was _removed_ from the JDK that is distributed by Oracle. It is now a separate library, and needs to be included with your application similar to any other third-party library.

Comment: @Slaw But Javafx with a Jar works without it, is that what you're saying?

Comment: Do you use the same JVM in vs code as on the command line?

Comment: vscode terminal:`java -version`
`java version "17.0.3.1" 2022-04-22 LTS`
and in mac Mac command line
`java version "17.0.3.1" 2022-04-22 LTS`

Comment: What does `java -version` output on your development machine? What does it output on the machine where you get the above error?

Comment: I ran `java -version` in the vscode terminal and then in my Mac terminal. Those are the outputs above.

Comment: Added into my question for clarity.

Comment: @Slaw I'm running everything on the same machine currently. I no longer have the old iMac Pro running Mojave that I mentioned. But all the Jars worked no problem as they were.

Comment: @Slaw To be clear I only have one Mac right now and it all works fine running directly in vscode but in a Jar the mediaplayer throws the error in the description. The Jar is built with Maven Shade inside of VSCode. The Jar works fine, the only problem is when playing a sound. I'm  not using `--module path` I'm just using Maven.

Comment: Okay. Since you mention Maven, am I correct in assuming you have JavaFX declared as a dependency in your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: @Slaw Yes it wouldn't work at all without that in the pom.xml file. `<dependency><groupId>org.openjfx</groupId><artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId><version>17-ea+7</version></dependency>`

Comment: Do you also declare a dependency on the `javafx-media` artifact?

Comment: @slaw No I don't have that dependency but it works fine in VSCode without it and no errors are displayed.

Comment: Declare that dependency and try building and running the JAR again. Does it work?

Comment: @slaw Yes that works. Why is it the Jar requires that but vscode doesn't?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Perhaps you have a JavaFX SDK installed and there's a configuration mismatch between Maven and VS Code. I'd likely need to actually _see_ your entire development environment to give a definitive answer, which can't happen here. At least you got the JAR to work. However, you may want to consider looking into deploying your JavaFX application via `jlink` + `jpackage`. Check out the "Packaging" section in the [JavaFX tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) for more information.

Comment: @slaw Yeah it's very odd, as we can see I have the same java version on both, doesn't seem to make much sense. That's why I couldn't understand why it worked but didn't work as a jar. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Your error is around the Media class which is in javafx-media, not javafx-controls.  Mac M1 support was only implemented relatively recently, and may not be available or stable in an early access distribution such as 17-ea+7.  You could try JavaFX 18.0.1 with JDK 18.0.1.  If you want a version of the JDK packaged for M1 which includes JavaFX, then you can use Liberica full JDK or [Zulu JDK FX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72793112/1155209).